# Dopamine is released in anticipation. What chemial is released when the reward is actually recieved and complete the feedback loop?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, dopamine, reward

[image]

The figure shows Twice as much dopamine was released when there is a 50/50 chance of getting the reward vs 100%.

So brain releases dopamine in anticipation of reward. But how does the brain confirm that the reward is actually recieved and how it makes sure that it needs to release more dopamine when the probablity of getting the reward is 50% ?

Comment: Welcome. Can you add your sources to the figure and the background information in your post?